# retina @2x image not crisp when scaled down on FF / Chrome

Tags: image, scale, antialiasing, retina

I feel silly posting this very basic html question, but I am thoroughly stumped. I have a 100x100 pixel graphic (test@2x.png) that I am serving up as an image and then resizing to 50x50. This should result in a crisp image for both retina and non-retina screens… but it does not (in Chrome and Firefox, Safari is fine).

That same image saved at 50x50 (not resized by CSS) and the original show okay at 100%, but when the original 100x100 is scaled down it get choppy.

Technically I do not understand how it is even possible for this to happen. Given that I have a retina screen it should be the exact opposite: images at 100% aren’t quite crisp and 2x images scaled to 50% are.

I must have done this a thousand times before without issue, anyone have any idea what’s happening?

```
<img src="http://stacyrobyn.com/dev/retina/test@2x.png" width="50" height="50" />
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pixeloco/84n141vc/

screenshot of what I’m seeing (iMac/retina support, Chrome v37): https://i.stack.imgur.com/asA42.png

Comment: I suspect the resizers in Chrome and Firefox are tuned for speed, not quality.

Comment: I'm assuming you're setting your media query to something like this. `@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {`

Comment: @pixeloco I wonder if it would be different with a jpeg instead of a png.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is that I am an idiot... iMacs do not have retina support. I especially like how I acknowledged what I was seeing was "the exact opposite" of what a retina screen should do (aka: showing like a non-retina screen) but didn't put two and two together. I'm going to go hide now....

Comment: I think you still have a valid question though, there was a definite difference between the screen capture and the manually resized image.